# Attach stdout of one docker container to stdin of another docker container

Tags: python-2.7, docker, stdout, stdin, docker-volume

I would like to pipe the stdout of a script in container A to stdin of container B and then pipe stdout of container B to stdin of container C. I would like to know what is the best practice to do the same.

Option 1

```
docker run -it ImageA python script1.py | docker run -it ImageB python script2.py |  \ 
docker run -it Image3 python script3.py
```

Option 2

Use a shared volume to store data that can be accessed by subsequent containers.

```
docker run -it -v /home/shared_volume:/container1_home/shared_volume python script1.py 

docker run -it -v /home/shared_volume:/container2_home/shared_volume python script2.py 

docker run -it -v /home/shared_volume:/container3_home/shared_volume python script3.py
```

Ideally, I prefer to not use shared volumes. The output of script1.py and script2.py produce intermediate files (or streams of data) that are in the order of several terabytes. I am not interested in these files, I would prefer to store only the results of script3.py to disk.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the same by running it without -t option; I was able to do sample one like below and it is working

```
$docker run -i ubuntu:xenial ls -l | docker run -i ubuntu:xenial wc -l
$20
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am aware that piping between docker containers will do what I want. Do you think this is the best practice when the data to be streamed is quite large (~ TB)  or is there a better solution?

Comment: I hope my answer worked for you and coming to your second question. I would recommend you to make use of Kafka or RabbitMQ Docker and write your program to act as producer (stdout) and subscriber (stdin);  This will help you to debug things when you want to play with data and see what is happening with your data between dockers.   Moreover, this kind of approach is good to go if you feel not to store your data in volume s or going with pipe option.